# Docker Ubuntu image missing many common binaries

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm comparing a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with its equivalent Docker image/container and I'm noticing many typical binaries like `vi`, `less`, `ping`, and so on are missing from the Docker version.

Just counting binaries in some key folders from the Docker container:

```
root@9769637f38c6:/# ls -al /bin | wc -l
89
root@9769637f38c6:/# ls -al /usr/bin | wc -l
236
```

And on the fresh Ubuntu VM I get the 174 and 650 binaries, respectively.

Why are they so different?

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `vi` or `less` inside a container? Even `ping` seems like a stretch to me.

Comment: Just checking things out, man...

Answer (score 4):

A fresh install of Ubuntu will have all the common commands and software installed for a General Purpose system.  On the other hand, Docker images are based on a "just enough" to run.  It's expected you would update the base image with just the software you need.

As an example, if you pull from Docker Hub a Wiki image.  You'll get an image with the base of Ubuntu that has the Wiki software install and nothing else.

Keeps it small.  Keep's possible problems to a minimum.

Comment: "Keeps it small. Keep's possible problems to a minimum". This must be written in some sort of IT bible.    Edited, punctuation.